In $\ell_p$, $0<p<1$, find a compact set whose convex hull is unbounded
The space $\ell_p$ is a metric space with the metric $d(x,y)=\sum\vert x(k)-y(k)\vert^p$. Also, I know that it's not locally convex.
I've chosen this sequence: $x_n=n^{p-1}e_n$, which goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity, and the set $K=\lbrace x_n\rbrace\cup\lbrace0\rbrace$, which is compact using sequential compactness in a metric space.
I still find working with convex notions in these spaces quite unintuitive, and my tries might not be in the right direction, but this might be a nice example to finally understand it.
My try: let $y_n=\frac{1}{n}x_1+\cdots \frac{1}{n}x_n$ a convex combination of the $x_i$ and let's show that it is arbitrarily away from the origin.
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \vert y_n(k)\vert^p=\frac{1}{n^p}+\frac{1}{n^p}2^{p(p-1)}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^p}n^{p(p-1)} = \frac{1}{n^p}(1+2^{p(p-1)}+\cdots+n^{p(p-1)}).
$$
From this point onwards, I don't seem to be able to show that is arbitrarily big. ¿Any help with this computation? Or is my reasoning even correct?

You are almost there. Let me set
$$
x_n  = n^{-s} e_n
$$
for some $s>0$ so that $x_n \to 0$.
Again we take
$$
y_n = \frac1n (x_1 + \dots + x_n).
$$
Now
$$
\sum_k |y_n(k)|^p = n^{-p} \sum_{k=1}^n k^{-sp}  \approx n^{-p} \cdot n^{1-sp},
$$
the latter is unbounded if $1-sp-p > 0$ or $s<\frac{1-p}{p}$.
Here, I used that for $q<1$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-q} \ge \int_0^n (x+1)^{-q} dx = \frac1{1-q} n^{1-q}.
$$
Edit: realized now that you only missed the latter estimate to compare the sum with the integral.
